# Get distinct value from comma seperated array using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

Supposed I have a string array like this

```
{
"A“，
”B",
"A,B,D",
"C"
}
```

Is it possible that I write a single LinQ to get the distinct values {"A","B","C","D"} into a List?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
lists.SelectMany(l => l.Split(',')).Distinct().ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var distinctValues = myList.SelectMany(x => x.Split(',')).Distinct().ToList();
```

This will split each string, and then flatten them into a single list, and get the distinct elements.

If you want to get the elements in alpha order, then you can tack on a `.OrderBy(x => x)` right before `.ToList()`.

Answer (score 1):

Fyi in linq query syntax its the same as the answers above

List s = new List() {
"A","B","A,B,D","C"};

var result = (from x in s from y in x.Split(',') select y).Distinct().ToList();